# Get match results by date

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, view

I got this database:
[image]

How can I select Matches by date? I want output like this: Barcelona (HomeTeam), 2 (HomeTeamScore), 2 (AwayTeamScore), PSG (AwayTeam).

I want to select all matches that played on some date and I need to COUNT result of teams from table PlayerMatch by players who score goals (In this case where Foreign key MatchId = 2  (table PlayerMatch) Messi score two goal for Barcelona, and Cavanni score 2 goals for PSG, so result will be 2:2).

Here is code to create tables and input some data:

```
CREATE TABLE Team(
TeamId          INT             IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Name            NVARCHAR(75)    NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Players
(
PlayerId int identity Primary Key,
Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
TeamId int,
FOREIGN KEY (TeamId) REFERENCES Team(TeamId)
);

CREATE TABLE Match
(
MatchId int identity Primary Key,
MatchDate date NOT NULL,
HomeTeamId int NOT Null,
AwayTeamId int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (HomeTeamId) REFERENCES Team(TeamId),
FOREIGN KEY (AwayTeamId) REFERENCES Team(TeamId)
);

CREATE TABLE PlayerMatch
(
PlayerMatchId int identity Primary key,
Goal bit not null,
PlayerId int not null,
MatchId int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (PlayerId) REFERENCES Players(PlayerId),
FOREIGN KEY (MatchId) REFERENCES Match(MatchId),
);

INSERT INTO Team (Name) VALUES ('Liverpool');
INSERT INTO Team(Name) VALUES ('Real Madrid');
INSERT INTO Team(Name) VALUES ('Barcelona');
INSERT INTO Team(Name) VALUES('PSG');

INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Roberto Firmino', 1);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Adam Lallana', 1);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Luka Modric', 2);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Benzema', 2);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Messi', 3);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Arda Turan', 3);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Cavani', 4);
INSERT INTO Players(Name, TeamId) VALUES('Lucas', 4);

INSERT INTO Match(MatchDate, HomeTeamId, AwayTeamId) VALUES ('06-06-2007', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Match(MatchDate, HomeTeamId, AwayTeamId) VALUES ('06-07-2007', 3, 4);


INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 1, 3);

INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 2, 7);
INSERT INTO PlayerMatch(Goal, MatchId, PlayerId) VALUES (1, 2, 7);
```

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: HomeTeam, HomeTeamScore, AwayTeamScore, AwayTeam. For example:
Barcelona - 2 -  2 - PSG

Comment: This database design has a flaw - What will you do when a player move from team x to team y? You have to keep the team players data with a start date and an end date (nullable) so that you will know who played for what team at the date of the match. It get's even more complicated if you want an accurate representation of the real world, since players may be loaned to a team. I've solved it by adding a table of players per match, but my client had a person to test the content of this table before the match started...

Comment: +++ for your formatting and script for tables / insert for tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.MATCHDATE, B1.NAME AS HOMETEAM, C1.GOAL AS GOAL_HOME, C2.GOAL AS GOAL_AWAY, B2.NAME AS AWAYTEAM
 FROM MATCH A
 INNER JOIN TEAM AS B1 ON A.HOMETEAMID=B1.TeamId
 INNER JOIN TEAM AS B2 ON A.AWAYTEAMID=B2.TeamId
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT MATCHID, TEAMID, COUNT(GOAL) AS GOAL
            FROM PLAYERMATCH 
            INNER JOIN PLAYERS ON PLAYERS.PlayerId=PLAYERMATCH.PlayerId
            GROUP BY MATCHID, TEAMID) C1 ON A.MATCHID = C1.MatchId AND A.HOMETEAMID=C1.TeamId
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT MATCHID, TEAMID, COUNT(GOAL) AS GOAL
            FROM PLAYERMATCH 
            INNER JOIN PLAYERS ON PLAYERS.PlayerId=PLAYERMATCH.PlayerId
            GROUP BY MATCHID, TEAMID) C2 ON A.MATCHID = C2.MatchId AND A.AWAYTEAMID=C2.TeamId
```

The output is:

```
MATCHDATE  HOMETEAM                                                                    GOAL_HOME   GOAL_AWAY   AWAYTEAM
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2007-06-06 Liverpool                                                                   2           1           Real Madrid
2007-07-06 Barcelona                                                                   2           2           PSG
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to pass MatchDate from application and then select only match which played in passed date.